# How to change Apache Jmeter Dashboard report title dynamically

Tags: java, jmeter, reporting, jmeter-plugins

I am struggling to set Apache Jmeter Dashboard report title **dynamically** as **Application/API name + Application/API version**, extracting the version from an API call.

Running my test from non-gui mode
[image: Non-GUI test run]

Jmeter version `5.3`

Have tried setting it through JSR223 PostProcessor
[image: JSR223 Script]

However, found that it isn't working
[image: Dashboard Report]

I was wondering if it is even possible that way dynamically (changing it at run time)

Any inputs much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As of JMeter up to 5.3 this is not possible as initialization of the report generator is done before running the test:

Init:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/44c0c7ee1a18b86528adf07607839614166d60f6/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L1068

Test start:

- https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/44c0c7ee1a18b86528adf07607839614166d60f6/src/core/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/JMeter.java#L1088